# How to adjust the window position when linking to another part of website?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm new to HTML and CSS and am trying to implement a navigation bar that sends the user to another part of my one-page website whenever they click on a link. I'm using anchors and reference links in order to achieve this. For instance, I'll have:

```
<a name="JR_Harrison_Target"></a>
```

and then use

```
[<a href="#JR_Harrison_Target">Introduction</a>][1]
```

to go to that location on the page. The only problem is that when I click on the link, it sends me to the page with a large margin of pixels at the top browser from the previous section of my website. This happens whenever I click a link to any and all sections. Is there any way to adjust the position of the anchor that I'm scrolling to so I can set up the window accurately? Thanks!

Example of problem:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a [MCVE]?

Answer (score -1):

Try to play with this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <a href="#3">3</a>
  <a href="#4">4</a>
</div>

<section id="1"></section>
<section id="2"></section>
<section id="3"></section>
<section id="4"></section>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: .5;
}

.menu a {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8m0w2aon/8/

As you can see - in order to make links work properly - you need to place the id prop on the section you'd like to scroll to. You'll be just "teleported" to the beginning of the section.

Each section should have fixed height, and no element inside it should come out of it (for example a background image which is bigger than the section itself).